# SQL Query from database schema with functional dependences. Normalization

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-normalization, sql-server-2014-express

I'm supposed to write a SQL query from given schema:

- `BookAuthors` (ISBN, authorName, gender, title, yearPublished, pubId, pubName, phone)
- `FD` = { ISBN -> title, pubId, yearPublished; authorName -> gender; pubId -> pubName, phone }

Here's what I wrote:

```
CREATE TABLE Authors
(
    authorName VARCHAR(64) PRIMARY KEY,
    gender CHAR(1)
);

CREATE TABLE Publishers
(
    pubId VARCHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY,
    pubName VARCHAR(64),
    phone NUMERIC(10)
);
GO

CREATE TABLE Books
(
    ISBN VARCHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(32),
    pubId VARCHAR(32) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Publishers(pubId) NOT NULL,
    yearPublished NUMERIC(4)
);
```

Is this the correct answer? I'm worried about not having any connections between author and the book.

Comment: `AuthorName` is a really bad idea for a primary key - first of all, there's absolutely a chance to have **two authors** with the same name, and secondly, such a large variable-length column is a **horrible choice** for a primary key in SQL Server and will have extremely poor performance

Comment: So what about authorName in books?  What about multiple Terry Mitchel - both male and female?

Comment: Am I allowed to add my own columns here, like authId or FDs when task gives me schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems come from the fact that in your functional dependencies is missing a dependence from ISBN to AuthorName: this is because each book uniquely determines its author. So the dependences should be:

```
ISBN -> title, pubId, yearPublished,  authorName
authorName -> gender
pubId -> pubName, phone
```

So, the third normal form is the following:

```
Books(ISBN authorName pubId title yearPublished) ,
{ ISBN → authorName pubId title yearPublished } >

Authors (authorName gender) ,
{ authorName → gender } >

Publishers (pubId pubName phone) ,
{ pubId → pubName phone } >
```

And this should be the set of relations that are to be defined. Of course, you should add the right constraints, like primary keys and foreign keys (and the solution of IrateB is correct as well).

I think this is an exercise, otherwise, you should add an AuthorId to your original data, and modify the functional dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

here is a suggestion;

**Authors** (authorID: integer, authorName nvarchar(32), gender: char(1))
*primary key*(authorID)

**Publishers** (pubID: integer, pubName: nvarchar(32), phone: nvarhcar(16))
*primary key*(pubID)

**Books** (bookID: integer, ISBN: nvarchar(32), title: nvarchar(32), authorID: integer, pubID: integer, yearPublished: integer)
*primary key*(bookID, autorID)
*foreign key*(authorID) references to Authors
*foreign key*(pubID) references to Publishers.

Last wednesday I finished my endtest 'Databases' (and I passed that test :-)) so I'm not a specialist. But I think you would be solid with this.
And yes, you can add your ownn columns, especially if it promotes unicity.
Book is considered as a 'weak enitity', that's why the primary keys also references to it's identifying entity.

Good luck,

B

Comment: What about FDs? Adding columns like IDs I'm changing FDs. Can I do that too?

Comment: Can you define FD's, please, never occured this during the course or maybe we use another name in Dutch

Comment: Functional dependency is a constraint where X implies Y.
Something like primary key I think. Value of Y is always the same for some X.

Comment: yes, I think I understand. In my example this is obtained if all attribute values are atomic (non-splittable) and by making a custom attribute like authorID. But like you can see in the answer of Renzo, there are higher levels of 'normal form', good luck!

Comment: Normalization never adds attributes that weren't in the original relations.

Comment: No, it doesn't, but it is obtained by  doing this if I'm correct? (1NF)

Comment: @IrateB: The question is about normalization. Database normalization never introduces new attributes. You introduced two new attributes and several new functional dependencies. You're not  doing normalization.